# flask render.template array result

Tags: python, arrays, flask

I use a rest API, to get some result, this work without any issues, but I will then print the result on an HTML page. Data is coming into an array. The problem is that the out is written as `Produkter ['Lagertrøfler', 'Skabelon', 'ZARKOPERFUME PINK MOLéCULE EDP 100ML']`

I will like each product on each line but can figure out

My py file is as follows

```
@app.route('/visprodukt', methods=['GET','POST'])
def visprodukt():



conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("www......dk")

headers = {
        }

conn.request("GET", "/wp-json/wc/v2/products/", headers=headers)

res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()
y = json.loads(data)



navne = []
for item in y:
    navne.append(item['name'])
print("Printer navne", navne)

itemsoutput = navne

ids = []
for item in y:
    ids.append(item['id'])
print("Printer id", ids)

itemsids = ids

return render_template('produkter.html', produkter = navne, ids = ids)
```

my html is as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<center><h3>Produkter {{ produkter }} <br> </h3></center>
<center><p><a href="\">Notificer en ny</a></p></center>






</body>
</html>
```

Anything I can do here?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate the [list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

{% for item in produkter %}
   <center><h3>Produkter {{ item }} <br> </h3></center>
{% endfor %}

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you very much. It works well, but if i also want the id variable to be printed, how to do this, sorry for this question, but can't figure out